# Brushed DC motor drive reverse-engineering

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I have a mains powered brushed DC motor drive capable of 800-1000W (allegedly). I am using it to power a threadmill motor, for power tool application.

The drive is quite simple and I worked out the schematics below:
[image: 10850H176767 Mains powered 800W DC Motor drive]

The micro-controller label has been made unreadable by the manufacturer, I used an ATiny20 for the schematics because it matches the pin count, but it's probably something else.

The main issue with this drive is that there is no ramping in the speed and the motor tries to go full speed instantly to full speed when switched on (assuming the speed setting pot was set to max). This is not desirable in my application and seems to be quite hard on the motor. I would much prefer to have a gradual acceleration for the motor to get to the set speed.

My plan to achieve this is to swap the micro-controller for an arduino so I can run my own firmware and add functionalities (mainly speed ramping, but options for E-Stop, visual feedback of the current, PID, etc).

Before that, I would like to understand how the current sensing works. Using an oscilloscope, I tried to slow down the motor by hand and I saw an increase of the voltage on pin10 by only a few mV.
Ideally I would like to understand how the voltage across R19 relates to the one seen by the microcontroller on pin10.

How is the sensed current meant to be processed by the microcontroller? Is it simply a safety feature that will cut the power if a max current is exceeded or there is more to it?

I am also interested if you have feedback on the drive electronics architecture. It was cheap and seems quite basic, yet it seems to be doing the job. Are there obvious shortcomings? What are expensive brushed motor drive doing differently to justify the price difference?

Edit: Photo of the board around the op amp
[image: Board picture]

Comment: Are you sure that the circuit around U2B is traced correctly? Can you show us a photo of the PCB in this area? What voltage is the mains?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I double checked and I think the schematics are fine, but I could be wrong. Mains is 240VAC.

Comment: That’s the least amount of gain I’ve ever seen in a current sense circuit, and yet with a 10b ADC you still get about 20mA per bit, which is perhaps enough resolution to satisfy someone’s requirements.